# Resize shrink in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to build a header across the top-center of the page with two names and a ring in between centered. I also have a picture centered in the middle of the page. Everything looks nice on a full screen laptop until I resize
the browser and everything moves and looks jumbled. I've read a lot of 
post and everyone says use a wrapper with a min width and user percentages along with that in your divs. I can't figure this out after a week of reading any
and everything I possibly could.

HTML:

```
<body> 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="michael">
            <p class="m">Michael</p>
        <div> 
        <div class="ringhead">
            <img  src="Images/gold.gif" class="ring"  alt="Wedding Ring" width="100" height="60">
        </div>
        <div class="christina">
            <p class="c">Christina</p> 
        </div> 
        <div class="weddingWebsite">
            <img class="wedding" src="Images/Wedding Website.jpg" alt="Wedding Website;">
        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;  
}

.michael{    
    color:#EEE8AA;
    position: fixed;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0%;     
} 

.m{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height 100%;     
}

.ringhead{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 4%;    
} 

.ring{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
} 

.christina{
     color:#EEE8AA;
     position: fixed;
     left: 70%;
     top: 0%;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 30px;
     max-width:100%;
     max-height: 100%;
 }

 .c{
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;   
 } 

 body{ 
     background-image: url("Images/Top Banner.jpg"), url("Images/MiddleBanner.jpg"), url("Images/Bottom Banner.png");
     background-size: 100% 10%, 100% 15%, 100% 100%;  
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;   
 }

 .weddingWebsite{
     position: fixed;
     top: 65%;
     left: 65%;
     transform: translateX(-65%) translateY(-65%);
     max-width: 80%;
     max-height: 60%; 
  }
  .wedding{
      max-width: 80%;
      max-height: 60%;
  }
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you use `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`

And you didn't close `div class="Michael">` properly you forgot the / in the closing div-tag.

I didn't have the picture but came up with something that works down to 500px in screen width.

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="michael">
                <p class="m">Michael</p>
                </div> 
            <div class="ringhead">
                <img  src="Images/gold.gif" class="ring"  alt="Wedding Ring" `enter code here`width="100" height="60">
            </div>
            <div class="christina">
                <p class="c">Christina</p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="weddingWebsite">
                <img class="wedding" src="Images/Wedding Website.jpg" alt="Wedding Website;">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 479px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding: 0 5%; */
    display: block;
}

.michael {
    color: #EEE8AA;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    /* left: 30%; */
    /* top: 0%; */
}

.m{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height 100%;     
}

.ringhead {
    position: relative;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* top: 4%; */
}

.ring{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
} 

.christina {
    color: #EEE8AA;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* top: 0%; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
}

 .c{
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;   
 } 

 body{ 
     background-image: url("Images/Top Banner.jpg"), url("Images/MiddleBanner.jpg"), url("Images/Bottom Banner.png");
     background-size: 100% 10%, 100% 15%, 100% 100%;  
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;   
 }

 .weddingWebsite{
     position: fixed;
     top: 65%;
     left: 65%;
     transform: translateX(-65%) translateY(-65%);
     max-width: 80%;
     max-height: 60%; 
  }
  .wedding{
      max-width: 80%;
      max-height: 60%;
  }
```

Here is the link to a fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/hzxsvLzz/1/

Comment: It worked thank you but not understanding why you made the div "wrapper" so small. I thought that the wrapper div needed to be very large. Just starting to learn.

Comment: It also has pulled all 3 headings down at least 5px past my Top Banner and into my middle banner also my picture is moved down about 4px when resized. Thanks for the help but been on this about a week, it's pretty frustrating.

Comment: For the `margin: 0 auto;` to work the wrapper can't be the full width of the page. 

If you want the wrapper to be the full with of the page. I would recomend using this to the wrapper:

`.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}`

and noticed now that the wrapper does not have any end tag

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion as for the wrapper and the class Christina

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion for the wrapper and the class Christian moved farther down the screen while ring and michael dropped down about 4 inches. Not sure what to do here. Nothing seems to work Been on stuck on this issue a week now.